# How to solve incorrect syntax of group by?

Tags: sql

I have a table in MSSQL as below :

[image]

I want to create a sql to select last bid record grouped by each productID.

So the result will be 3 records (row 13, row 15 and row 17).

My current sql is something like this :

```
select top 1 * 
from Bid 
order by bidDate desc
group by productID
```

There is an error shown :

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: which database are you using? mysql? postgres? mssql?

Comment: SQL-Server but which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax near group by may be, unless you are in mysql, because you can't SELECT * in a GROUP BY query.

To solve your problem you can:

```
SELECT 
    B.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        MAX(bidDate) maxDate,
        productID
    FROM
        Bid
    GROUP BY
        productID
    ) Q INNER JOIN Bid B
    ON Q.maxDate = B.bidDate
    AND Q.productID = B.productID
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query has two errors.

1. `group by` is first and `order by` afterwords.
2. You can only `select` (without agregate functions like `count`, `sum`, `avg`, etc.) the columns in the `group by`

---

To solve your query, do it like this:

```
select b.*
from Bid b
inner join (select max(bidDate) as maxDate, productID from Bid group by productID) aux
  on aux.productID = b.productID and aux.maxDate = b.bidDate
```

Comment: You haven't got bidDate in your result to do ORDER BY.

Comment: now the error becomes Column "Bid.bidDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. @@